# Maximum of oscillator displacement due to one phonon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phonons

let's say I have a mechanical mode with frequency $\omega$ and effective mass $m$. I put one phonon in that mode and want to get an estimate (or ideally) calculate the *maximum* displacement of my mode (i.e. my oscillator) from its equilibrium position. So basically the QM equivalent of $x_{max}$ in a classical description.

Intuitively, the max. displacement should scale with the phonon number, for $|n\rangle$ I should get a larger displacement than for $|0\rangle$. It should also scale with the zero-point fluctuations $x_{ZPF}$

However, I am lacking the tools to formally show that. I ofc. know that I can rewrite $\hat{x} = x_{zpf}(\hat{b} + \hat{b}^{\dagger})$, but if I apply $\hat{x}$ to my Fock state I just get a weird expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation value of $\hat{x}$ in the Fock state $\lvert n \rangle$ is of course zero, because $\hat{b}$ and $\hat{b}^{\dagger}$ both connect only Fock states that satisfy $\Delta n = \pm1$.  However, one might define an effective classical maximum displacement as the root-mean square, i.e.,
$$
x_{\textrm{max}} :=\sqrt{\left\langle \hat{x}^2 \right\rangle}\,.
$$
In this case, then, we get
$$
\left\langle \hat{x}^2 \right\rangle =
\langle n\rvert \hat{x}^2 \lvert n \rangle
= x_{zpf}^2\left(
0+
\langle n \rvert\hat{b}\hat{b}^{\dagger}\lvert n \rangle
+\langle n \rvert\hat{b}^{\dagger}\hat{b}\lvert n \rangle
+0
\right)
=
x_{zpf}^2(2n+1)\,,
$$
(using linearity of the inner product and the fact that, e.g. $\langle n \lvert \hat{b}^2 \rvert  n \rangle=0$)
so that
$$
x_{\textrm{max}} = x_{zpf}\sqrt{2n+1}\,.
$$

---

An alternative here is to consider the fact that for the harmonic oscillator,
$$
\langle \hat{x} \rangle (t) = \langle \hat{x} \rangle (0)\,\cos(\omega t) + \frac{1}{m\omega}\langle \hat{p} \rangle (0)\,\sin(\omega t)\,.
$$
This is true for *any* state $\lvert\Psi(x,t)\rangle$. For Fock states, both $\langle \hat{x} \rangle (0)$ and $\langle \hat{p} \rangle (0)$ are zero, and so the expectation value is zero. However, we can consider the (non-stationary) states that are considered to be the "most classical", i.e., the coherent states $\lvert \alpha\rangle$, given by
$$
\lvert \alpha\rangle = e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}\lvert n \rangle\,.
$$
For coherent states,
$$
\langle \hat{x} \rangle (0) = \frac{\alpha+\alpha^*}{2}\,,~~~~~~~
\langle \hat{p} \rangle (0) = \frac{\alpha-\alpha^*}{2i}\,.
$$
The time-dependence of the coherent states is simple, i.e.,
$$
\lvert \alpha (t) \rangle = \lvert e^{-i\omega t}\alpha(0) \rangle\,,
$$
and this leads exactly to the expressions above.

Finally, the coherent states are eigenstates of $\hat{a}$, i.e.
$$
\hat{a} \lvert \alpha \rangle = \alpha \lvert \alpha \rangle\,,
$$
and so there's a sense in which $\alpha$ (the effective amplitude of the oscillatory motion) "scales" with $\hat{a}$, which is sort of like a square-root of $\hat{N} = \hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}$.  So in this picture, there's still a scaling of the amplitude with $\sqrt{n}$, in a sense.

Comment: Nice. This makes sense. Why does it intuitively make sense to relate the fluctuations to a classical maximum displacement? I.e. why $$x_{\textrm{max}} :=\sqrt{\left\langle \hat{x}^2 \right\rangle}\$$ makes sense?

Comment: That's sort of just how things are *always* done in cases where the average values are zero.  Consider the case of a random walk, in which an object takes a step of one unit to the right or left with equal probability at each time step.  It should be clear that the average of the *position* of the walker will be zero. However, if we ask for the average *distance* (i.e. $\langle |x| \rangle$) from the origin traveled, that will be non-zero.  $\langle |x| \rangle$ is hard to compute, so we replace it with $\sqrt{ \langle x^2 \rangle}$ instead, which is fine in most cases.